# What's the point of QoS settings and multiple channels in PHP AMQP implementations?

Tags: php, concurrency, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

Since PHP is single-threaded there doesn't seem to be a point to increasing QoS/prefetch values and using multiple channels when working with AMQP.

I could maybe see a point in something like ReactPHP, but in the usual circuimstances the whole app is going to be blocked while a single message is being processed, so you can't exactly work on multiple messages at the same time (which is the point of QoS). And similarly, it is my understanding that you would use multiple channels to be able to have concurrent data transfers in the same AMQP connection, but here also because of PHP being single threaded, it's not like you can send/receive data through different channels in the same time.

*tl;dr;* What's the point of using multiple channels and QoS > 1 when working with `php-amqplib`?

Comment: There might not be a particular point to it, but it's in the AMQP spec, so it's in the lib that implements the spec. Additionally, while the userspace PHP code that _you_ write does indeed run in a single-threaded manner, there are other aspects that carry on at the same time, eg: data arriving via a socket or other IO, or extension code running under certain circumstances.

Comment: You've kind of answered your own question: there _are_ asynchronous processing runtimes for PHP, so if nothing else, the feature is useful for them.